# Fit img height to second cell of the table, that has dynamic height

Tags: html, css

First cell contains an image, that has 100% width, and dynamic height.
I have miniatures in second cell, every of the miniature, should get 33% of second cell dynamic height.

```
<div style="display: table; width: 50%; height: auto;">
  <div style="display: table-cell; background: red; width: 70%;">
      <img src="IMG_15052014_112112.png" style="width: 100%;">
  </div>        
  <div style="display: table-cell; background: blue; width: 30%;">
    <img src="IMG_15052014_112112.png" style="height: 33%;">
    <img src="IMG_15052014_112112.png" style="height: 33%;">
    <img src="IMG_15052014_112112.png" style="height: 33%;">        
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use table so you can vertically span table rows

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td rowspan="3"><img src="IMG_15052014_112112.png" alt="" /></td>
       <td><img src="IMG_15052014_112112.png" alt="" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><img src="IMG_15052014_112112.png" alt="" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><img src="IMG_15052014_112112.png" alt="" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanx for your help. Your answer is almost good, but I have ng-repeat in angular as min images.